# Can a Canadian living in Australia leave to UK during current COVID restrictions?

Tags: uk, australia, covid-19, canadian-citizens

My girlfriend is a Canadian citizen, visiting Melbourne, Australia on a work visa.

I am able to leave Australia, and travel back to England using my British passport, because I am a dual citizen of Australia and United Kingdom.

However, my girlfriend is Canadian, so she does not have a British passport.

This leads me to my question . . .

**Can she currently travel directly from Australia to the UK without restriction?**

Comment: There would be no pure restrictions on her ability to travel. It's just that she might have to quarantine for some period of time after arrival. There is a list of countries to which this applies.

Comment: Australia is currently on the UK’s travel corridor list, so self-isolation on arrival is not required https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-travel-corridors A Passenger Locator form must be completed before travel https://www.gov.uk/provide-journey-contact-details-before-travel-uk Local Covid Alert Levels apply in certain areas https://www.gov.uk/guidance/local-covid-alert-levels-what-you-need-to-know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

There are currently no restrictions on travellers from Australia entering the UK. See the list of exempt countries here https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-travel-corridors.

You must complete a passenger locator form before you arrive in the UK from any country https://www.gov.uk/provide-journey-contact-details-before-travel-uk and you should check the area(s) where you will be staying for local restrictions. Certain areas are currently classified as Very High under the newly-introduced Local Alert framework https://www.gov.uk/guidance/local-covid-alert-levels-what-you-need-to-know

Australian Covid restrictions mean that Australian citizens and permanent residents can only leave Australia if they have an exemption. Applications for an exemption should be made at least two weeks, but not more than three months before the planned travel date. If granted an exemption, evidence of that exemption decision must be taken with you to the airport. https://covid19.homeaffairs.gov.au/leaving-australia

Comment: There actually *are* restrictions on leaving Australia, but as a non-citizen the OP's GF is exempted.  However, since the OP is a citizen, they do have to apply for permission! https://covid19.homeaffairs.gov.au/leaving-australia

Comment: @lambshaanxy Thank you, I will add this to my answer